# Zebra ZPL file: Print a SGD parameter

Tags: zpl, sgd, zebra

I have a label file in ZPL format for a ZD621.  I have (3) of these printers on my network and would like my labels to show which printer it came from.  I used the SGD setvar "device.friend_name" to give the printers names.  I would now like to include that variable in my ZPL file and print it on the label.  I can't find anything in the manual on how to pass variables like this.

I tried this code and it printed out {device.friendly_name} instead of the saved name

^XA
^FT380,270^A0N,22,21^FH^FD{device.friendly_name}^FS
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ